# Using glfx.js filters in Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

I am building a simple canvas application using Fabric.js. While things are looking good, I am interested in some filter effects to make it a little cooler. After some searches I came across through various sources. But I am particularly interested in glfx.js library.

I couldn't find any particular way to integrate Fabric.js with glfx.js. glfx.js seems to have its own canvas classes `fx.Canvas` so I am a little worried that it will not be possible to integrate the two.

My question is, is it possible to use other libraries like glfx.js with Fabric.js? Because I can't find out how.

If not, if I am using Fabric.js will I be needing to write my own filters to get those effects?

http://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/docs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's fairly easy to create new filters in Fabric.

If you look at the [source of Sepia filter](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/src/filters/sepia_filter.class.js), for example, you can see that [`applyTo` is responsible](https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/blob/master/src/filters/sepia_filter.class.js#L32-L46) for actual pixel-per-pixel processing. When `applyTo` is called, it's being passed a canvas element representing image onto which filter is being applied to. You modify an image by modifying this corresponding canvas element (`getImageData` -> pixel processing -> `putImageData`).

But what about glfx.js?

I see that `fx.canvas()` returns a newly-created canvas, with already initialized WebGL context. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to support *accepting* already existing canvas element, to operate upon. If it did, we could do this:

```
...
applyTo: function(canvasEl) {
  var fxCanvas = fx.canvas(canvasEl);
  fxCanvas.ink(0.25).update();
}
...
```

But as it stands right now I don't see a way to integrate it with Fabric filters.

Comment: Either file an issue with glfx.js to support accepting existing canvas element, or create custom filter in Fabric (there's a tons of available filters there already, btw).

Comment: But they are extremely slower ,and the convolute kernel is also very slow when I apply it on a image of 255KB. How to write our own custom filters to integrate to Fabicjs?

Answer (score 2):

I use this http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/11/fast-image-filters-with-webgl its fast its not as smooth as `glfx.js` but i does great job!

I use it kind of dumb because of the small size images, i get the object `activeObject.getSrc();` then I add it to a temp canvas apply the filter and add it again in canvas!